# KUSTO split txt when ingesting

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-storage-account

I created a table in my Azure Data Explorer with the following command:

```
.create table MyLogs ( Level:string, Timestamp:datetime, UserId:string, TraceId:string, Message:string, ProcessId:int32 )
```

I then created my Storage Account --> Container and i then uploaded a simple txt file with the following content

```
Level Timestamp UserId TraceId Message ProcessId
```

I then generated a SAS for the container holding that txt file and used in into the query section of my Azure Data Explorer like the following:

```
.ingest into table MyLogs (
h'...sas for my txt file ...')
```

Now, when i read the table i see something like this

```
Level                                            TimeStamp  UserId  TraceID  MEssage ProcessId
Level Timestamp UserId TraceId Message ProcessId
```

So it basically put all the content into the first column.
I was expecting some automatic splitting. I tried with tab, spaces, commas and many other separators.
I tried to configure an injection mapping with csv format but had no luck.

For what I understood, each new line in the txt is a new row in the table. But how to split the same line with some specific separator?

I read many pages of documentation but had no luck

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any of the formats that you want to try using the format argument, see the [list of formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-supported-formats) and the ingestion command syntax example that specify the format [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-storage)

In addition, you can use the "[one click ingestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/one-click-ingestion-new-table)" from the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (I have done it before with Python SDK)

````
.create table MyLogs ingestion csv mapping 'MyLogs_CSV_Mapping' ```
[
  {"Name":"Level","datatype":"datetime","Ordinal":0}, 
  {"Name":"Timestamp","datatype":"datetime","Ordinal":1},
  {"Name":"UserId","datatype":"string","Ordinal":2}, 
  {"Name":"TraceId","datatype":"string","Ordinal":3}, 
  {"Name":"Message","datatype":"string","Ordinal":4}, 
  {"Name":"ProcessId","datatype":"long","Ordinal":5}
]```
````

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-storage

```
.ingest into table MyLogs SourceDataLocator with (
   format="csv",
   ingestionMappingReference = "MyLogs_CSV_Mapping"
)
```

Hopefully this will help a bit :)